# Introduction Screen Button ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-xml

I'm facing an issue regarding intro screen in android. 
I create `button` in one fragment but i'm trying to call this button in `welcomeActivity` through `layoutinflate` in activity but it doesn't perform any functionality.

XML Fragment(custom_intro):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
    <Button
        android:id ="@+id/explore"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Explore"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

WelcomeActivityLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <!--tools:showIn="@layout/welcome_activity"-->


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

WelcomeActivityJava:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.welcome_activity);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_intro, null);
Button button=(Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.explore);
button.setText("Test");

 Int[] layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.custom_intro,
                R.layout.custom_intro1,
                R.layout.custom_intro2,
                R.layout.custom_intro3,
        R.layout.custom_intro4};


       myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
        viewPagerIndicator.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPagerIndicator.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the Button of Fragment inside its parent Activity then you should define a method inside your Fragment class like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

TextView mTextView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    return view;
}

public void setButtonText(String value){
    mTextView.setText(value);
}
}
```

Then you can use this inside your Activity like this:

```
myFragment.setButtonText("Test");
```

Comment: what if i want to call second fragment through this button

Comment: if you want to call another fragment from the current fragment    


public void callNextFragment(){
NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag,"findThisFragment")
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();    
}

Comment: call this method from parent activity